# Is it okay to have a PCI-e back panel missing from the case?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building, case

This is the first computer I've ever built, and coming from a mentality of "never read the manuals ever", I obviously made a few mistakes along the way. One of these mistakes was installing the graphics card into the wrong slot, limiting it to x8 instead of x16. This also means I broke off the metal strip in the back of the case for the graphics card, but now I want to move it to the correct slot, which means I'll have to break off another metal strip.

My question is, is it okay to leave a hole in the case where the graphics card used to be? I no longer have the original metal strip, so I can't simply leave it in place. Even if I could though, it's physically broken off, so I doubt it would be very secure.

Comment: You can buy a blank plate to cover the hole. Something like [this](https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/products/main/PLATEBLANKLP.Main.jpg)

Comment: Or http://www.ebay.com/itm/5x-PCI-Slot-Cover-Dust-Filter-Blanking-Plate-Hard-Steel-Black-w-screws-/261448385336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it ought to be safe.  Those plates are sometimes referred to as "dust covers" (or "slot covers").  If you don't have the plate covered, there is a larger opening that dust can enter the system.  (Fans usually aren't pointed at the slots to blow dust out in that direction.)  It's also big enough that some bugs might be able to crawl in.  Admittedly, that seems rather unlikely.  However, it is more likely than if the dust cover was still blocking access.

Another option is to just buy any expansion card... maybe more USB ports, or a network card, and simply cover the hole that you made.  However, if you don't wish to do that, I wouldn't worry a whole lot about it.  Many systems have a slot cover missing.

Comment: I like the idea of adding another card. More USB ports never hurt, and my computer is lacking in the 3.0 department.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly safe.  So long as the rest of the framework for holding in the addon cards is in tact, then you're fine.  Those metal strips are there to keep big things out of the system, like items inserted by children, or larger critters.  They can also reduce the inflow/outflow of air when they're blocking the slot; however this only really matters to hardcore gaming/workhorse machines.

> "never read the manuals ever"

In my experience, that was perfectly reasonable a long time ago; however with everything getting more and more complex, I personally believe that it's best to at least glance at the manual for any gotchas before building something.

Comment: One time when I lived in the country, I left my computer off for two weeks and came back to find it booting only intermittently. Mice had chewed through the HDD ribbon cable and its conductors were now intermittently touching. I fixed it, dumped out the nest (babies and all, as I recall) and put metal tape (available where ductwork is sold) over the empty card spots.

Comment: By which I guess I mean that _it's perfectly safe_ and _Those metal strips are there to keep big things out of the system, like [...] larger critters_ are opposite ideas, depending on whether you occasionally have mice, as most country dwellers in my area do. Rework to make the answer more self-consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it off isn't ideal, since the case helps keep the RF emitted from your system inside the case so, theoretically, it won't interfere with your other household electronics. One could argue that it might disrupt the internal air flow, but I think the risk is negligible.

I've never had a problem running my systems this way. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to buy a new ***PCI slot cover dust filter*** which will be cheaply available in your local market or you can check online. This will keep your PC dust-free, make it more secure and put an end to you worry.

Answer (score 0):

Those dust cover are usually of standard size and standard colors (silver or black). It means all the old cases have them. Just "procure" several dust covers from old cases of your friends or friendly computer stores and use them. Cheaper than buying.