# Case back slot removed

Tags: case

I have a NZXT S340 Elite case and I attached a video card, removing a couple of horizontal plates as usual. This is ok since it is a huge 1080 Ti.
But, in order to do so, I also had to remove the vertical plate which is in correspondance of the screws of each horizontal plate.

Now I got this piece off and I don't know if I have to remount it, because as you can see in the image there is a huge hole now in the back of the case and I don't think it's safe.

Do I have to remount it inside, and, is it possible even if I have the video card?

[image: photo]

Comment: Similar question: [*Is it okay to have a PCI-e back panel missing from the case?*](https://superuser.com/q/1101716/432690)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its fine, no you don't have to remount it. That panel is probably there for vertical placement of your graphics card and/or water cooling. If it was a problem your PSU would be as well.

Personally I'd remount it as it probably looks better and might lead to ever so slightly less dust entering your case.